# JavaFX: JMetro change Progress bar color

Tags: java, javafx

I am using `JMetro`'s indeterminate progress bar. From the documentation, i use the below `css` to have a fade in effect:

```
.progress-bar:indeterminate .dot_1 {
    -fx-background-color: ACCENT_COLOR;
}

.progress-bar:indeterminate .dot_2 {
    -fx-background-color: derive(ACCENT_COLOR, -15%);
}

.progress-bar:indeterminate .dot_3 {
    -fx-background-color: derive(ACCENT_COLOR, -30%);
}

.progress-bar:indeterminate .dot_4 {
    -fx-background-color: derive(ACCENT_COLOR, -45%);
}

.progress-bar:indeterminate .dot_5 {
    -fx-background-color: derive(ACCENT_COLOR, -60%);
}
```

This works as expected . But the progress bar color is default blue and i want to change it to white.

Simply changing the `-fx-background-color: white` or adding `-fx-accent:white` is not working.

How can i do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-fx-background-color: white` instead of using color name.. Using the Hexadecimal value of the respective color solved the issue.